# Downcast Spring Factory Bean

Tags: spring

// Two third-party factories:

```
public class OneStaticMethodFactory {
 ...
 public static Object createFactory(String oneInstanceMethodFactoryClassName) {
  ...
 }
}

public class OneInstanceMethodFactory {
 ...
 public OneObject createObject() {
  ...
 }
}
```

// Hardwired code:

```
OneInstanceMethodFactory oneInstanceMethodFactory = 
 (OneInstanceMethodFactory) 
  OneStaticMethodFactory.createFactory("pkg.to.OneInstanceMethodFactory");

OneObject oneObject =
 oneInstanceMethodFactory.createObject();
```

// Attempt to replace them by Spring beans:

```
<bean id="oneInstanceMethodFactory" class="pkg.to.OneStaticMethodFactory"
 factory-method="createFactory">
  <constructor-arg value="pkg.to.OneInstanceMethodFactory">
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="oneObject" factory-bean="oneInstanceMethodFactory"
 factory-method="createObject">
</bean>
```

// Run Spring IoC:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'oneObject' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
No matching factory method found: factory bean 'oneInstanceMethodFactory'; 
factory method 'createObject()'. 
Check that a method with the specified name and arguments exists and that it is non-static.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:528)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1015)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:605)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:925)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:472)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(DelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:228)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
        ... 26 more
```

To solve the problem above, how to **downcast** oneInstanceMethodFactory bean from compile-time type Object to runtime type OneInstanceMethodFactory in Spring? (Modification of the two third-party factory classes would not be the point on question.)

**@EDIT**

Thanks to the hints from `@Boris Treukhov`, finally i figured out that the problem had nothing to do with `type downcast` but indeed `OneStaticMethodFactory#createFactory` returned other runtime type than `OneInstanceMethodFactory` due to a typo myself. Now everything works as expected after the migration from the hardwired code to `Spring IoC / DI` above.

Comment: Are you sure that createFactory returns a OneInstanceMethodFactory  instance?

Comment: Yes when i manually wired them in java code.

Comment: And they are not implementing any Spring interfaces?

Comment: What is 'oneInstanceMethodFactory', if you temporarily comment out `oneObject` definition? Is it really a `OneInstanceMethodFactory`? Everytime I had this error it always ended up that there's really was no such a public non-static method. Downcasting makes no difference because the methods are called through reflection method which takes Object as argument.

Comment: Ok then. I've upgraded the comment to the answer.

Comment: Thanks again for your great help, and the answer has been accepted, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that `'oneInstanceMethodFactory'`, is really a `OneInstanceMethodFactory` instance, either by checking what bean type was created with name `"oneInstanceMethodFactory"`  through the container's `getBean()` method  or by examining the value returned by `createFactory` in the debugger.

In my experience this exception is very straightforward, usually there's really no  such a public non-static method.

Downcasting makes no difference because the methods are called through the reflection method which takes an `Object` instance as `this` argument. The bean type is determined by the value returned from the factory method, Spring don't need to know the class before the bean is initialized. In fact `oneObject` bean depends on `oneInstanceMethodFactory` so the latter bean will be fully initialized before the former, and the Spring will be able to call its `createObject` method.